# Proving equality of 2 continuous function on a point under certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I need help in this question->

Assume S(z) and S'(z) are two complex functions both continuous on X ={ z$\epsilon$ Complex numbers : z$\geq$1 } which are equal on |z|>1.

> By which result it can be deduced that both S'(z) and S(z) are equal on |z|=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|z|=1$ then $z_n =(1+\frac 1  n )z \to z$ and $|z_n| >1$ for all $n$. Hence $S(z)=\lim S(z_n)=\lim S'(z_n)=S'(z)$.

Comment: Maybe this is not a right way to approach you but since you have answered a lot of questions of mine can you also have a look at this question in complex analysis to which no one is answering :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888622/looking-for-a-solution-of-this-problem-without-using-schwarz-lemma-and-blaschke